# Pass multiline html string(markdown text) from rails to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a markdown text saved in the databse and I want to show it as html to the user. I am using markdown.js as the processor and  I pass the big multiline html string from rails to javascript by rendering a js.erb file from the controller.

But since it is multiline, the javascript becomes invalid. Is there any rails function which will take the whole string and assign it as a single line string to javascript variable. I cannot use html_safe also as some things might be escaped. What is the best way to handle markdown?

sample markdown

```
![enter image description here](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiOb7-0qeyx73XuXNqzLpxgXTlf5UMrMnF5zm-UKn3wLaXCW0UUw "enter image title here")
```

1. Hello

Comment: If you render erb server-side anyway, why not have markdown rendered server-side as well?

Comment: can u tell me how to do that?

Comment: Added my advice as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you render erb server-side anyway, you will probably be better rendering Markdown server-side as well. You can use [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for that.

1. Add `gem redcarpet` to your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Use it:

   ```
   text = "my _markdown_ *variable*"
   markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
   markdown.render(text)
   ```

It will be a good idea to save rendered HTML in the database, to save CPU time on re-rendering the same text every time you want to show it to client. So you can add something like this to your model:

```
class Article
  # let's say that model has 'source' attributes with Markdown
  # and we want to put resulting HTML into 'html' attribute
  before_save :markdown

  def markdown
    self.html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML).render(source)
  end
end
```